# Generate striped blocks of indexes from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of *n* length and I want to generate a new array to act as a list of its indexes such that the indexes are "striped" into blocks. By "striping" I mean that we'll move up the indexes from A-Z in an incremental fashion multiple times, retaining a patterned order.

For example, let's say our array has 30 elements, indexes 0-29.

I want to be able to provide an integer to act as a factor that speaks to how "mixed up" I want the stripes to be; how many blocks I want the indexes reordering into.

Factor 1 (reorder the indexes into 1 block - obviously nothing happens)

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
```

Factor 2 (reorder the indexes into 2 striped blocks)

```
[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,  1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29]
```

Factor 4 (reorder into 4 blocks)

```
[0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,  1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,  2,6,10,14,18,22,26,  3,7,11,15,19,23,27]
```

Factor 7

```
[0,7,14,21,28,  1,8,15,22,29,  2,9,16,23,  3,10,17,24,  4,11,18,25,  5,12,19,26,  6,13,20,27]
```

I don't need to reorder the original array or even to produce this reordered list in full - I just need to loop over the existing array items and work out what position their index would put them in this theoretical reordered list.

The function should obviously work for an array of any length, and any block factor (as long as it's an integer).

One key thing is that the block lengths will differ if `n % f !== 0`. Take our factor 4 list above, where we have two blocks of 8 indexes, and two blocks of 7 indexes. Similarly for the factor 7 list we get two blocks of 5 indexes and five blocks of 4 indexes.

We can work out several things quite quickly:

```
const perGroup                    = arrayLength / blockSize;
const largeGroupCount             = arrayLength % blockSize;
const indexThatSmallGroupsStartAt = largeGroupCount * Math.ceil(perGroup);
```

The question is - **how do I get from this point to the finished function?**

I'm part of the way there but I think I am hugely overcomplicating it and need a fresh pair of eyes (or brain) to help me finish it up!

```
for (i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++){
  const groupSize = i < indexThatSmallGroupsStartAt ? Math.ceil(perGroup) : Math.floor(perGroup);

  const newIndex = ???
}
```

I've been trying to work out the group number at the moment and the position of the index in the new group but I'm not entirely sure either, or both, are necessary... (so this code is omitted from above)

*The reason I'm "striping" the indexes in steadily increasing groups like this is because they're going to be used to pull colours out of a spectrum. So you can imagine each group will traverse the whole spectrum of colours, but each element in any subsequent group will be shifted along the spectrum incrementally from where that element in the previous group would have been. I have an array of stuff I need a colour for and a function that already exists to pull an array of colours out of my spectrum. So I want to loop over each of the items in my original array and use the newIndex to get the colour from my colours array.*

Comment: Just so I understand correctly - you want to do this in place, without generating any extra arrays to hold the elements, is that correct?

Comment: @VLAZ yeah I'll add a little extra information to the end of the post. I'd like to solve it without generating any extra arrays but I'm happy to do if it's just a whole lot easier.

Comment: It would be easier, as you can just break down your main array into `f` number of arrays and then join them up replacing the original. However, that will take up `O(n)` space as you need to double up your storage (e.g., with `f = 3` you'd generate 3 arrays holding a total of `n` entries). However, it's also doable in place. Trickier but at the very least you can reduce the extra space requirement to simply `f` - you can calculate the cutoff points where each section starts and store those indexes. So with `f = 3` you'd only have three entries there.

Comment: Are you always going to have input that's divisible by the factor, or can you also have, for example `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` with factor `4`? And if that's a valid case, what should be the output: `0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3` (first two "sub-groups" are larger, the last ones are smaller).

Comment: definitely cannot rely on it being divisible, as per the factor 4 and 7 examples on the array of 30. But yes, I think if you're splitting into groups it makes sense for the first ones to be the largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill the array in order by just resetting the loop counter.

```js
function stripe(length, blocks) {
  let a = new Array(length);
  let i = 0;
  for (let j = 0; i < length; ++j)
    for (let k = j; k < length; k += blocks)
      a[i++] = k;
  return a;
}

console.log(...stripe(30,1))
console.log(...stripe(30,2))
console.log(...stripe(30,4))
console.log(...stripe(30,7))
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is much faster than Nina Scholz's approach. https://jsbench.me/l3khkrgk8a/1

Comment: I love both, but I'll accept yours on the basis of speed and - though arguably this should not be a factor - readability to a sub-JS guru-level dev like I. I should have just gone for the "create an array of indexes" approach from the off but once I started down the "work it out for a particular index individually" route I wanted to find a way to do it... oh well, I'll drop that investigation and use your method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could take a function which assembles the parts.

```js
function getParts(length, parts) {
    return Array
        .from(
            { length: parts },
            (_, i) => Array.from(
                { length: Math.floor(length / parts) + (i < length % parts) },
                (_, j) => i + j * parts
            )
        )
        .flat();
}

console.log(...getParts(10, 2));
console.log(...getParts(10, 7));
```